# cordova-plugin-contacts not loading contacts in samsung s8

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap

cordova-plugin-contacts is not loading contacts in S8 but its loading contacts and working fine in all other mobile phones. It's wrok fine in all other devices too. but not working on S8.